# Pandas - Change the value of cells in data frame based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame (df):

```
colA   colB   colC
X      red    0
X      blue   0
Y      red    0
Y      blue   0
```

I wish to update a specific cell in colC based on conditions in other columns. Example: update all colC values to 1 where colA = X & colB = blue.

I've tried using the df.at and df.loc functions. Unfortunately, I was getting indexing errors. Not entirely sure I understand how to use them properly.

```
df.loc[df['colA'] == 'X' & df['colB'] == 'blue', df['colC']] = 1
```

I expect the following outcome:

```
colA   colB   colC
X      red    0
X      blue   1
Y      red    0
Y      blue   0
```

Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 2 problems - missing `()` around conditions because priority precedence  and for set new column is necessary only column name:

```
df.loc[(df['colA'] == 'X') & (df['colB'] == 'blue'), 'colC'] = 1
```

Comment: That worked - thank you so much. I understand better now.